# rounding off whole number vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem about the format of the number in my on-going program in VB.Net

My Question is, How can i round it off the Non-Decimal Number in VB.Net by the ruling of
every Hundredth Digit of the Number :

In two Scenario

*if the Hundredth Digit is equal or below 499 (a <= 499 )will go to 500 :

example:

From 1488 --> 1500
From 1,000,320 ----> 1,000,500

*if the Hundredth Digit is equal or above 500 (a >= 500) will go to 1,000:

example:

from 1500 --> 2000

from 1,000,700 ---> 1,001,000

I used by VB6 style, but its not working anymore,

please help me.

Thank you

Comment: Is this homework? lets see what you have so far

Comment: First show your effort... only then we can help you...

Comment: can i post any images here? i'm still new in vb.net, so I still use my vb6 method to complete some syntax

Comment: .net includes the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace, so you could still use the VB6 call. Post your code using that, and ask how it can use the System.Math namespace instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the examples in the question:

```
Private Function CustomRound(input As Integer)

    Dim roundUpTo500 = (input Mod 1000) < 500

    If (roundUpTo500) Then
        Return Math.Floor(input / 1000) * 1000 + 500
    Else
        Return Math.Round(input / 1000) * 1000
    End If

End Function
```

gives the following results:

```
  CustomRound(1488)    -> 1500
  CustomRound(1500)    -> 2000
  CustomRound(1000320) -> 1000500
  CustomRound(1000700) -> 1001000
```

Comment: Hello, Mr. Adrian... Thank you For your Reply, and it's really working :), I used it for my salary rounding off for my people here...

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```c#
// Pass value to round off here
private int ValueRoundOff(int value)
{
    int returnValue = 0;
    bool isHandling = true;
    for (int it = 500; isHandling; it += 500)
       {
           // While it is handling it will check if the value you passed is less 
           // than to 500, if not it will add another 500 to make it 1000 
           // and check again
           if (value < it)
           {
              returnValue = it;
              isHandling = false;
           }
       }
    return returnValue;
}
```